# Javascript dialogs usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have not much experience in web development and I have some problems with action confirmation on my site admin panel. As I know, JS have standard confirmation dialog etc. So should I use this to confirm user action or it will be better to write custom modal window ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to avoid usage `alert()` `prompt()` and `confirm` and use custom dialogs.
There are many libraries that you can use instead of js dialogs (for example: [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) or [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

Also check this fresh article: [Chromium policy on JavaScript dialogs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy)

Did you already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359807/why-shouldnt-i-use-alert-in-javascript)?

Comment: A pretty good library that I can't stop using is sweet alert [ http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert] . It provides callback function on confirm/cancel/close.