# get JSON from PHP with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a html form in my index.php
I have my connection.php who receive the login and the password... check it into the database... and return true if the user is auth or false if not..

I return this into a json format with json_encode(array('result' => 1));
but when I try to display the result with my jquery, I have a blank page.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ticket v1.0 Administration</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Système de ticket par Sami Jnih" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="ticket" />
    <meta name="author" content="Sami Jnih" />
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skins/css/form.css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="index">

    <div class="container">
        <section class="main_login">

            <form id="connection" class="form_login" name="form1" action="connection.php" method="POST">
                <h1><span class="log-in">Connexion</span> ou <span class="sign-up">inscription</span></h1>
                <p class="float">
                    <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Login</label>
                    <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Login" required="required" />
                </p>
                <p class="float">
                    <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Mot de passe</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword" required="required" />
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <a href="signup.php" class="inscription">Inscription</a>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Connexion"/>
                </p>
                <br />
                <p id="auth"></p>
            </form>​​

        </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin.login.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery file:

```
$("#connection").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(json){
            if (json.auth === 1)
            {
                $("#auth").css({
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    color: 'green'
                }).text('Connexion réussi, redirection en cours..').show().fadeOut(3000);
                window.location.replace("http://sami.fr/admin/contents/home/index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#auth").css({
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    color: 'red'
                }).text('Erreur, identifiants incorrects!').show().fadeOut(6000);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, error){
            $("#auth").text('Erreur : ');
            $("#auth").after('<p>' + jqXHR.responseText + '</p>');
            $("#auth").after('<p>' + error + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

connection.php

```
    $rootPath = '';
require_once ($rootPath . 'application.php');

session_id(generateID($_REQUEST));
session($_REQUEST['login']);

if ( $user = authUserAccess($_REQUEST) )
{
    if ( !fetchSession(session_id()) && !checkSession(session_id()) )
        addSession($user, session_id());
    else
        updateSession($user, session_id());

    $result = array('auth' => 1);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else
{
    closeSession();

    $result = array('auth' => 0);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Now All is working!

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `alert()` for verifying receipt - it interrupts your JavaScript and may cause further issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825384/alert-is-bad-really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `return` in your php file, you need to actually output the data, via echo (with the correct header):

```
if ( $user = authUserAccess($_REQUEST) )
{
    if ( !fetchSession(session_id()) && !checkSession(session_id()) )
        addSession($user, session_id());
    else
        updateSession($user, session_id());

    $result = json_encode(array('return' => 1));

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $result;
    // header('Location: ' . $adminContentPath . 'home/index.php?sid=' . session_id());
}
else
{
    closeSession();

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('return' => 0));
}
```

Also, as noted by pmandell, your callback has inconsistent names for the returned data

Lastly, you must stop the form from submitting normally else the user will get redirected:

```
$('#connection').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ ...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

On all tutorial, They didn't teach how to return JSON data from PHP... I didn't knew for the header('Content-Type: application/json') !

Why can't I return an array with json_encode?

Comment: @SamiJnih `json_encode` will work with any valid php variable, array or object. You are using it with an array in your example, so im not sure what you mean. Also, if this answer solved your problem, why did you mark the other one as correct??

Comment: because both of solutions makes my jquery/php working.. I can't put 'solve' on the two solutions :/

Comment: @SamiJnih Ok, sure. Please see my edit regarding your blank page problem

Comment: @SamiJnih The form isnt supposed to submit, because you are sending the data via ajax. Does your success function fire (do you see the alert)?

Comment: @SamiJnih i see in your edit that you are not passing ev to the function. Should be `$('#connection').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();` note this part `function(ev)`

Comment: I forgotten to add (ev) into my post, but in my code, I don't forgot ten it.

But... If it isn't supposed to submit, I have to have my <p> include into my div.. but I have nothing when I press 'submit'. I don't know about wich alert you are talking about :/

If I json.response === 0, I want to make a header to another page with is displayed only when I'm auth

Comment: You removed the alert in an edit! What browser are you using? if chrome, look into the javascript console for any errors. Also add an error function to your ajax to debug errors: `error:function(data){console.log(data);}`

Comment: I added the alert, it works but I never got my <p> which include the text result. I'm using chrome :/ And the callback error doesn't run, no error in the javascript console

Comment: OK, spotted the error - in your js you check `json.response` but in php you create `json.return`. change your js to `if ( json.return === 1 ) {...`

Comment: @SamiJnih well if the alert fired, then the ajax is working, just not your appending code. You need to debug it. instead of the alert, add `console.log(json);` and look into the javascript console and see what you get.

Comment: Object { readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: .ajax/x.setRequestHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/x.getAllResponseHeaders(), getResponseHeader: .ajax/x.getResponseHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/x.overrideMimeType(), abort: .ajax/x.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), promise: .Deferred/d.promise(), 11 de plus… }

Comment: That looks like the jqxhr object, very odd - try renaming json to data?

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
success: function(json){
    alert(data);
    if ( data == 0 ) 
        $("#resultat").html("<p>Vous êtes connecté.</p>");
    else
        $("#resultat").html("<p>Erreur, login ou mot de passe incorrect.</p>");
    }
```

You are attempting to reference **data** which is not defined.

**data** is frequently what jQuery developers name the .ajax() success parameter. You can name it whatever you want. You could change your code to:

```
success: function(data) {
    ...
}
```

Also, the parameter of the success callback will be the JSON that the AJAX request responds with. In this case, it is an object with one attribute, **response**. You will need to check the value of response with:

```
if ( data.response === 0 ) {
    $("#resultat").html("<p>Vous êtes connecté.</p>");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!

I have some questions:

-If a want to do the same of header('Location: index.php') in PHP with jquery, how can I do this?

-If I have more than 1 value in my json, can I do something like a FOREACH or a FOR to parse the json?

-I have a blank page with '{"return":1}', how can I use my index.html and display my <p>vous etes connecté</p> into the <div id="resultat"> please :) ?

Comment: If you have additional questions you need to start new topics on them.