# If your only tool is an alert box, then

Tags: javascript, alert

A coworker came into my office and showed me [A Smarter Way to Learn JavaScript](http://www.asmarterwaytolearn.com/js/index-of-exercises.html), which he thought was great. I told him I didn't like the author's method of delivery, but my coworker left thinking that he was going to learn JavaScript by going through these exercises.

So now the problem is: in every design meeting, my coworker suggests that we use an alert box to notify the user of something important.

I'm trying to come up with a clever quote to say during our next meeting. Something like:

> If your only tool is an alert box, then all your problems...

But I can't seem to find a clever ending. What should I say the next time he proposes using an alert box?

Comment: Tell him to use console.log and explain why its better for debugging.

Comment: This isn't a coding question and is opinion-based. Probably better for a chat room.

Comment: If you have access to change some site he is using (maybe something internal), just place an alert everywhere so he'll understand how bad idea is it, when he will constantly popped alerts.

Comment: You're asking for the punchline to a joke on SO.. a 15k user should know better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

Alert is bad simply because it has no positive features and only negative features

- blocks the entire browser
- blocks the javascript thread
- only prints strings
- requires user interaction to continue (this means you can't automate browser usage)
- is blocked by common popup blockers
- doesn't work in non-browser environments like node.js (however console.log does work in node.js)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825384/alert-is-bad-really)

Comment: Points 1, 2, and 4 are the exact reasons why it has a use-case. Not often, but sometimes you want everything to halt and force user interaction before proceeding.