# How to create date filter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have JSON data which has structure as follows:

```
data = [
{
    "id": 100,
    "floorplans": [
        {
            "bhk": 1,
            ...some other fields
        },
        {
            "bhk": 3,
            ...some other fields
        },
        {
            "bhk": 2,
            ...some other fields
        }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2016-08-21"
},
{
    "id": 200,
    "floorplans": [
        {
            "bhk": 1.5,
            ...some other fields
        },
        {
            "bhk": 1,
            ...some other fields
        },
        {
            "bhk": 2.5,
            ...some other fields    
        }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2017-08-21"
},
{
    "id": 300,
    "floorplans": [
        {
            "bhk": 1,
            ...some other fields
        },
        {
            "bhk": 4,
            ...some other fields
        },
        {
            "bhk": 2,
            ...some other fields
        }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2018-08-21"
}]
```

Now above data is getting stored inside filterOptions array. Now filterOptions example:

filterOptions ["Ready", 2, 4, 1]  -> this means filter all the data which has 2,4,1 BHK included and also that data which has possession_date < current date

filterOptions ["Under construction", 3]  -> this means filter all the data which has 3 BHK included and also that data which has possession_date > current date

So I have the code as follows:

Note: I am using .slice() because I am comparing date of form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
function checkStatus(options, date) {
  console.log("Status: ", options)
  const currentTime = moment().format();
  let d1 = Date.parse(currentTime.slice(0,10));
  let d2 = Date.parse(date.slice(0,10));

  if(options.includes("Ready")){
    if(d1 > d2)
      return true;
  } else if(options.includes("Under construction")){
    if(d1 < d2)
      return true;
  }

}

 var display_filtered_projects = data.filter(
        (item) => item.floorplans.some(val => filterOptions.includes(val.bhk))
        && checkStatus(filterOptions, item.possession_date));

    console.log("display_filtered_projects: ", display_filtered_projects);
```

If I remove `checkStatus(filterOptions, item.possession_date)` then the filter works perfect but only for BHK type. Now I have to combine it with date how can I do that ?

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you weren't cramming multiple condition types into `temp`

Comment: @Phil I want to create date filter with existing BHK type filter. So how can I combine both of them and create one single filter which is combination of date and BHK type  In future if I want to add some more fields from JSON data then how can I create a generic filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use separate filter lists. (Based on discussion with you in Discord)

```
import moment               from 'moment'
import React                from 'react'
import ReactDOM             from 'react-dom'


const FIELD_DATE = `possession_date`

const yourMegaListFromStackoverflow = [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "floorplans": [
      {
        "bhk": 1,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 3,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 2,
      }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2016-08-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 200,
    "floorplans": [
      {
        "bhk": 1.5,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 1,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 2.5,
      }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2017-08-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 300,
    "floorplans": [
      {
        "bhk": 1,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 4,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 2,
      }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2018-08-21"
  }
]

const statusType = {
  'READY': `READY`,
  'UNDER_CONSTRUCTION': `UNDER_CONSTRUCTION`,
}

const statusMap = {
  [statusType.READY]: `Ready to move`,
  [statusType.UNDER_CONSTRUCTION]: `Under Construction`,
}

const statusList = Object.keys(statusMap)

const FilterStatus = (props) => {
  const {
    activeList = [],
    onClick,
  } = props

  return statusList.map((name) => (
    <div
      key={name}
      style={{ fontWeight: activeList.includes(name) && `bold` }}
      onClick={() => onClick({ name })}
    >
      {statusMap[name]}
    </div>
  ))
}

const typeType = {
  'UNO': `UNO`,
  'DOS': `DOS`,
  'TRES': `TRES`,
  'TRES_PLUS': `TRES_PLUS`,
}

const typeMap = {
  [typeType.UNO]: `1 BHK`,
  [typeType.DOS]: `2 BHK`,
  [typeType.TRES]: `3 BHK`,
  [typeType.TRES_PLUS]: `3+ BHK`,
}

const typeFilterMap = {
  [typeType.UNO]: (value) => value === 1,
  [typeType.DOS]: (value) => value === 2,
  [typeType.TRES]: (value) => value === 3,
  [typeType.TRES_PLUS]: (value) => value >= 3,
}

const typeList = Object.keys(typeMap)

const FilterType = (props) => {
  const {
    activeList = [],
    onClick,
  } = props

  return typeList.map((name) => (
    <div
      key={name}
      style={{ fontWeight: activeList.includes(name) && `bold` }}
      onClick={() => onClick({ name })}
    >
      {typeMap[name]}
    </div>
  ))
}

const App = () => {
  const [filterStatusList, filterStatusListSet] = React.useState([])
  const [filterTypeList, filterTypeListSet] = React.useState([])

  const onFilterStatusClick = React.useCallback(({ name }) => {
    filterStatusList.includes(name)
      ? filterStatusListSet([])
      : filterStatusListSet([name])
  })

  const onFilterTypeClick = React.useCallback(({ name }) => {
    filterTypeList.includes(name)
      ? filterTypeListSet(filterTypeList.filter((value) => value !== name))
      : filterTypeListSet([...filterTypeList, name])
  })

  const list = React.useMemo(
    () => {
      const now = Date.now()
      return yourMegaListFromStackoverflow.filter((doc) => {
        const date = moment(doc[FIELD_DATE]).format(`x`)

        const isStatusOk = filterStatusList.includes(statusType.READY)
          ? now > date
          : filterStatusList.includes(statusType.UNDER_CONSTRUCTION)
            && now < date

        return isStatusOk
          && doc.floorplans.some(
            ({ bhk }) => filterTypeList.some(
              (name) => typeFilterMap[name](bhk)
            )
          )
      })
    },
    [filterStatusList, filterTypeList]
  )

  return <>
    <FilterStatus
      activeList={filterStatusList}
      onClick={onFilterStatusClick}
    />

    <FilterType
      activeList={filterTypeList}
      onClick={onFilterTypeClick}
    />

    {list.map((doc) => (
      <div key={doc.id}>{doc.id}</div>
    ))}
  </>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can modify your filter logic to:

```
let filterData = data.filter(
  a => a.floorplans.some(e => temp.includes(e.bhk))
  && checkStatus(temp[2], a.possession_date)
);
.
.
.
function checkStatus(status, date) {
  if (status === 'Ready') {
    return new Date(date) < Date.now();
  } else {
    return Date.now() < new Date(date);
  }
}
```

***EDIT***
Assuming you only want to check for `'Ready'` in the temp array:

```
let filterData = data.filter(
  a => a.floorplans.some(e => temp.includes(e.bhk))
  && checkStatus(temp, a.possession_date)
);
.
.
.
function checkStatus(temporaryData, date) {
  if (temporaryData.indexOf('Ready') !== -1) {
    return new Date(date) < Date.now();
  } else {
    return Date.now() < new Date(date);
  }
}
```

***EDIT 2***

in the `display_filtered_projects.push(x);` part, I am not sure if you are expecting `y` otherwise. The catch here is that if `data` contains repeated results, they would end up being added repeatedly. *I have updated code to use Set to solve this.*

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 100,
    "floorplans": [{
        "bhk": 1,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 3,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 2,
      }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2016-08-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 200,
    "floorplans": [{
        "bhk": 1.5,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 1,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 2.5,
      }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2017-08-21"
  },
  {
    "id": 300,
    "floorplans": [{
        "bhk": 1,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 4,
      },
      {
        "bhk": 2,
      }
    ],
    "possession_date": "2018-08-21"
  }
]

var filterOptions = ["Ready", 2];

function checkStatus(options, date) {
  // console.log("Status: ", options)
  let d1 = Date.now();
  let d2 = new Date(date);

  if (options.includes("Ready")) {
    if (d1 > d2)
      return true;
  } else if (options.includes("Under construction")) {
    if (d1 < d2)
      return true;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
var display_filtered_projects = new Set();

data.filter(
  (item) => checkStatus(filterOptions, item.possession_date)
).forEach(x => x.floorplans.forEach(y => {
  if (filterOptions.includes(y.bhk)) {
    display_filtered_projects.add(x);
  }
}));

console.log("display_filtered_projects: ", Array.from(display_filtered_projects));
```

The additional problem here is that your date logic which I have reused would return nothing if the project status wasn't part of your input. So maybe in that case, you just want to return true for all. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: "Ready" and "Under construction" can be present at any position i.e 0, 3, 1 etc in temp array or may not be present in tempArray then how can I modify the code ?

Comment: what date would you like to get when you have neither `Ready` nor `Under construction` in the array. let me know so i can update the code.

Comment: the fiddle you provided is more confusing. the logic's not quite clear there. Also, I'd advise against using js `alert`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825479/11065438)

Comment: Check modified question let me know if you are still confused with my question.

Comment: i think i figured out what you want. check the update

Comment: no need of set I am making sure that only single value is added in filterOptions not repeated

Comment: yes, but as `floorplans` is an `Array` in itself, my `push` is nested too deep and can end up having multiple entries. Remove `"Ready"` from my `filterOptions` and use an `Array` instead of `Set`. It will give the clear picture of what I am saying.

Comment: If I run the snippet then I cannot see any result why so ?

Comment: something to do with SO's console display. I'll update code to use `Array.from()`

Comment: Were you able to have a look again?