# How to refactor this jquery code blocks into one block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery codes like this:

```
    $("#inputMobile").keypress(function(event){
        var ew = event.which;
        if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
            return true;
        if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
            return true;
        if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
            return true;
        alert("Change your keyboard language to English");
    });

    $("#inputEmail").keypress(function(event){
        var ew = event.which;
        if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
            return true;
        if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
            return true;
        if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
            return true;
        alert("Change your keyboard language to English");
    });
```

As you can see the main functions are same but the input id is different because I want to apply it into the both input fields.

So my question here is that, how can I refactor this code into one block of function and remove the extras ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback functions are identical, so just combine the selectors into one.

```
$("#inputMobile, #inputEmail").keypress(function(event){
    var ew = event.which;
    if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
        return true;
    if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
        return true;
    if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
        return true;
    alert("Change your keyboard language to English");
});
```

Note that [`.which` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which). Better to use `.key` or `.code` to check which key was pressed. You could also condense the check into a concise regular expression.

```
$("#inputMobile, #inputEmail").keypress(function(event){
    if (/[\da-z]/i.test(event.key)) {
        return true;
    }
    alert("Change your keyboard language to English");
});
```

You also might consider using a [proper modal instead of `alert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825384/alert-is-bad-really), and that one could well press non-alphanumeric characters even on an English keyboard. A more precise message would be something like "Only alphanumeric characters are allowed."

Answer (score 0):

```
const handler = function(event) {
  var ew = event.which;
  if (48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
    return true;
  if (65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
    return true;
  if (97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
    return true;

  alert("Change your keyboard language to English");
};
    
["#inputMobile", "#inputEmail"].forEach(selector -> $(selector).keypress(handler));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleKeypress(id){
    $(`#${id}`).keypress(function(event){
        var ew = event.which;
        if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
            return true;
        if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
            return true;
        if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
            return true;
        alert("Change your keyboard language to English");
    });
}
```

And now you can call it however times you want with `handleKeypress("inputMobile")` and `handleKeypress("inputEmail")`.

Hope it helps